# Which of the two design patterns should I implement in a 3-tier Asp.Net application?

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns

I’m trying to decide which of the two factory patterns I should use in my Asp.Net applications:

1 : All `DAL` providers derive from same abstract base class `DepartmentsProvider`, which defines public interface of the class ( all the necessary `CRUD` methods for which derived classes  (providers ) provide a concrete implementation ).  `BLL` layer instantiates correct provider by calling `DepartmentsProvider.Instance`:

```
public abstract class DepartmentsProvider
{
   static private DepartmentsProvider _instance = null;
   /// <summary>
   /// Returns an instance of the provider type specified in the config file
   /// </summary>
   static public DepartmentsProvider Instance
   {
       get
       {
           if (_instance == null)
               _instance = (DepartmentsProvider)Activator.CreateInstance(
                  Type.GetType(Settings.Departments.ProviderType));
           return _instance;
       }
   }

   public abstract List<Department> GetDepartments ();
   }
   /// Concrete provider
   public class SqlDepartmentsProvider : DepartmentsProvider
   {
       public override List<Department> GetDepartments()
       {
           using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
           {...}
       }
   }
```

2 :

```
public class DepartmentsProvider
{
    static private DbProviderFactory _instance = null;
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an instance of the FactoryProvider type specified in the config file
    /// </summary>
    static public DbProviderFactory Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = (DepartmentsProvider)Activator.CreateInstance(
                   Type.GetType(Settings.Departments.ProviderType));
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public static List<ForumDetails> GetDepartments()
    {
        DbConnection cn = Instance.CreateConnection();
        ...
    }
}
```

In first case we implement new provider by deriving from `DepartmentsProvider` class, while in second case new provider is implemented by deriving from `DBProviderFactory`.

What are pros and cons of each implementation?

Much appreciated

Comment: Why are you using singletons? Are they really needed?

Comment: I'm not familiar with singletons or design patterns in general. I only learned about the two patterns described above and that's it.

Comment: Singletons are evil when it comes to the persistence layer, scope the instances to the HTTP request. Neither implementations are good, i suggest you do some reading on design patterns such as the repository pattern, and dependency injection.

Comment: By persistence layer you mean DAL? What do you mean by "scope the instances to the http request"?

Answer (score 0):

Like RPM1984 I would suggest looking at the repository pattern and dependency injection.

You wouldn't want to use a singleton here as the connections may remain open and you may run into unforeseen issues.